# Cywgin and sshd file permissions are being randomally reset

Tags: cygwin, sshd

I have Cywgin running on a windows VM and I'm having problems keeping a stable SSHD service running.

The issue is that file permissions on the /etc/ssh_host_ecdsa_key, /$home/.ssh etc directories are being randomly reset so SSH connections are refused because I am using strict mode. When I stop the SSHD service, reset all the file and folder permissions to 700, restart SSHD, SSH connections work fine until they apparently randomly stop and sure enough all the relevant sshd directory and file permissions are reset.

Has anyone encountered this problem before and know a possible solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case somebody is researching a similar issue, the problem was due to instability on the VMs C drive after hibernating, logging off etc.

The solution was instead of installing Cywgin directly on the VM, install Cywgin a separate networked drive mounted on the VM. Works perfectly and no more instability issues.